# gpg passcode error

Tags: gnupg

I just created my gpg key using developer.ubuntu.com packaging page's documentation and also upload the public key in key server. When i import the key into launchpad it sent me an encrypted message. Now i give a command to decrypt the message

```
gpg -d launchpad.txt
```

it asked for a passcode. I gave one which i used to create gpg key. but it shows error again again. I repeat the process(gpg creation) again but stuck on .... passcode(decryption). What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with password & keys tool.